# How to handle socketIO connection error [connection error] recv disconnected by SSL ([SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_BAD_RECORD_MAC]?

Tags: python, ssl, socket.io

I am runing serval https web tests via python socketIO_client (and then import code into robotframework )to get capture specific socketIO notifications.  But sometime, the connection died in keeping wait for connection.

Errors could be seen, such as:

> 192.168.0.1:7777/socket.io [connection error] recv disconnected by SSL ([SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_BAD_RECORD_MAC] sslv3 alert bad record mac (_ssl.c:1754))
>
> 192.168.0.1:7777/socket.io /restNotificationsPath [socket.io waiting for connection]

**My question is how to hanlde these exceptions to successfully sleep for a while then reconnect?**

I have tried to search for solutions, and find two possible approaches to solve this.
1. Using namespace, and overwrite on_connect() to check the connection status. But my checking approach is not working. I have check namespace is_connected and some attributes, but seems they are not represent the conecntion status.
2. When setup the socket connection, using a pool to hold session, then there is a followed question, how to fire reconnect from robotframework?

Attached is my code:

```
import json
import sys
import logging
import time

import requests
from socketIO_client import SocketIO, BaseNamespace, ConnectionError
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
from robot.utils.asserts import fail

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class MyNotificationNamespace(BaseNamespace):
    @classmethod
    def setConnectedCallBackAndkwargs(cls, connectCallback):
        if connectCallback :
            cls.connectCallback = connectCallback
    @classmethod
    def setHitCallbackAndKwargs(cls, hitCallback):
        if hitCallback:
            cls.hitCallback = hitCallback

    @classmethod
    def setTargetEventType(cls, targetEventType):
        cls.targetEventType = targetEventType

    @classmethod
    def setTargetEventContent(cls, targetEventContent):
        cls.targetEventContent = targetEventContent

    @classmethod
    def setPath(cls, targetNotificationPath):
        cls.path = targetNotificationPath

    def on_connect(self):
        self._io.hit = False

        print('Connected to socket io, and set hit flag to False')

        if self.connectCallback:
            print "when connected, execute connect callback function without kwargs"
            #this will let robotframework execute keywords as callback
            BuiltIn().run_keyword(self.connectCallback)

    def on_event(self, name, data):

        if name == self.targetEventType and data === self.targetEventContent:

                print "Hit, receive target notification, set hit flag to True"

                self._io.hit = True
                if self.hitCallback is not None:
                    print "execute hit callback, when capture the target notification"
                    #this will let robotframework execute keywords as callback
                    BuiltIn().run_keyword(self.hitCallback)
        else:
            logger.debug("This is not target notification: %r,data:%r" % (name, json.dumps(data)))


def setupSocketIO(serverIp, headers, targetEventType, targetEventContent, waitTimeout, connectCallback=None, hitCallback=None):
    serverURL = 'https://' + serverIp

    nameSpace = MyNotificationNamespace
    nameSpace.setPath("/restNotificationsPath")
    nameSpace.setTargetEventContent(targetEventContent)
    nameSpace.setTargetEventType(targetEventType)
    nameSpace.setConnectedCallBackAndkwargs(connectCallback)
    nameSpace.setHitCallbackAndKwargs(hitCallback)

    try:
        with SocketIO(serverURL, 7777, verify=False, headers=headers) as socketIOInstance:
            socketIOInstance.define(nameSpace, '/restNotificationsPath')
            socketIOInstance.wait(int(waitTimeout))
            if socketIOInstance.hit:
                return socketIOInstance.hit
            else:
                return False
    except ConnectionError as err:
        print "Connection has error:" + str(err.message)
        print "continue without block whole test"
        pass
```